# Is it possible to configure where Fiddler should generate autoresponder files?

Tags: fiddler

Currently, in Fiddler2, when I go to `Autoresponder` tab, select an item, right click it and choose `Generate File`, Fiddler will generate the autoresponder file on my `Desktop`.

Is it possible to configure this folder somehow?

Answer (score 0):

No it isnt. It would just dwld it to your desktop.